# How to extract variable data from a netcdf file with shapefile?

Tags: r, shapefile, netcdf, masking

I am not getting the "lat" and "long" value for the shapefile I used to mask the netcdf file in R.

Here is the link to the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Feww0VvEq9SuJ4j4gxuVqvxpp_w8PVC/view?usp=sharing

I read both netcdf and my area of interest shapefile in R. I converted my shapefile projection to match the projection of netcdf file. I masked the netcdf file with my shapefile boundary. I write the variable value to a csv file. Although, I get the data for the entire time period, however, I do not see the lat and long values of the grid points. please suggest a way forward. Thanks

```
library(ncdf4)
library(ncdf4.helpers)
library(PCICt)
library(rgdal)
NC = brick("Daily_Pr_Inmm_Souris_1979_2016.nc")
SHP=readOGR("Souris_basin.shp")
crs(NC)
crs(SHP)
SHP=spTransform(SHP, crs(NC))
Souris_Pr_Daily=mask(NC, SHP)
tab=as.data.frame(na.omit(Souris_Pr_Daily[],xy=TRUE))
write.csv(tab, "Souris.csv")
```

I should see something like this in my csv file where Var 1 and Var 2 represent long and lat and the rest represent data for the entire time period

```
    Var1            Var2       X1            X2           Xn
1   -104.6875   47.8125 4.320732594 1.342601776    --------
2   -104.5625   47.8125 4.630135059 2.880001545    --------
3   -104.4375   47.8125 3.533707142 0.539954007    --------
```

Comment: Could you provide a link where we can access the "Daily_Pr_Inmm_Souris_1979_2016.nc" file and the "Souris_basin.shp" file please so that we can attempt to replicate your result and try to solve the problem please?

Comment: Hello NM, find the link to the data: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15Feww0VvEq9SuJ4j4gxuVqvxpp_w8PVC/view?usp=sharing